# mongodb change stream, operation update, how to solve get previous value problem

Tags: mongodb, firebase-realtime-database, triggers

I know that this feature is not implemented by mongodb. I am thinking what can be best way to achieve that.

Using caching service ? The approach will work but there is one problem, when the query You watch on is too big, like whole collection, You will never have the first before value, because You start caching only when first change appear on watch.

1. Service started watching.
2. Received object id 1, no cache for previous change, caching value.
3. Received object id 1, cache for previous change, can do comparison, caching value

I see another problem here, if I have 2 watchers which could potentially receive information about the same object, this will cause sync problems, as one process may update cache and second will already receive wrong data, hm. I mean the second process could be in a situation that cached previous value is already the same as the one in mongodb change stream.

I was thinking as well about mongodb replicas, but not sure if the problem can be solved with it.

Best,
Igor

Comment: Are you trying to create some sort of `onUpdate` triggers like Firebase?

Comment: @Dharmaraj yes, it is almost completed, we do it on Alibaba Cloud, but there is this one obvious problem, that I am not sure how to approach :)

Comment: ok can be solved with pre-image support, version 4.3.4